# How to make a video for YouTube on Linux?

Tags: sound, video, youtube, video-recording

In many YouTube videos there is a guy talking something to his laptop and recording a movie with his laptop built-in camera and a microphone. My questions are:

1. What program do you recommend to shoot such video in Linux?
2. How to get rid of a horrible static noise? On my HP Pavilion I can record sound but when I turn up "L R Capture" to 100% in order to gain the best sound volume in output recording I can hear a clear background noise. [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/362175/how-to-kill-tv-like-static-noise-in-my-linux-microphone)  someone has said that it's impossible to remove this sound. But there is no such noise in YouTube videos! How do they do that?

Answer (score 10):

I personally use the same I'd use on windows :

OBS studio.

the setup of desktop + webcam or just webcam is intuitive.

in a terminal type

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ffmpeg osb-studio -y
```

personally I record sound separately (when I want to have high quality) using Audacity (I would do the same with windows) and I use audacity's [noise reduction method](https://theaudacitytopodcast.com/tap012-how-to-remove-noise-with-audacity/) to clean up the audio.

then I put the audio and video together in an editing app. Kdenlive in my case.

it's a bit more work but if you're not willing to invest in better hardware (good sound card or external mixer for static-isolated audio + good microphone) that's what it'll be.

Comment: Great answer, a set of useful tools !

Comment: How do you sync the audio with the video if they are recorded in separated programs?

Comment: @Jirico I produce an audio file (mp3) from the audio recording program and I produce a video file (mp3, flv) from the video rocording program, I open up kdenlive, load both files into a new project put the video file on the video track and put the audio file on the audio track, sync up the two, cut to size and then export an new mp4 video file from this kdenlive project.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried several desktop recording programs, and I'd probably have to say the best is VLC. To record the desktop, go to Media -> Convert/ Save, select the "Capture Device" tab, then set "Capture Mode" to "Desktop." I trust you can figure it out from there.

As for sound recording, I trust the advice of the other folks on Superuser. Pros who do videos often buy microphones that they plug into their computers to get great audio quality.

[EDIT]: To use the webcam to record, follow the instructions as above except instead of "Capture Mode" being "Desktop," make it "Video for Linux" and select your devices in the slots below. As per the static noise (again), there may be a way to filter it out of the audio using a video editing program (OpenShot, Lightroom) or an audio editing program (Audacity comes to mind). However, I'm hardly an expert film maker.

Comment: Hi Jern, I rather meant how to record my own face. You know, like in the popular video-blogs that many folks have today. It strikes me that I watch many of videos any day and the sound quality is superior, and definitely not all of these people are experts in this area.

Comment: Whoops, my bad. I just edited my response to be more appropriate.