# Recommended video creator for YouTube on Ubuntu?

Tags: sound, video, files, youtube

In short I actually want to upload some audio to YouTube. You Tube only takes video. Obviously.
So I want to make an audio book type file; an audio file and a single image turned into a video file. I know which formats etc I need, as this are determined by the Chocolate Factory.

All of the Ubuntu video editing programmes are just that, video editing. For making "proper films". I've tried to make things like Pitivi work but they don't really do what I want, or at least I can not make it happen. Pitivi is very good but I can make it do the simple stuff.

Odd, a colleague has a Windows machine and the "photo" programme does exactly what I need. Choose a single image, add a sound file and it will "make a video" from the combined.

In short, is there anything Ubuntu that will do the same; a simple tool for a simple man wanting to do a simple job ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a video for YouTube on Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297973/how-to-make-a-video-for-youtube-on-linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally use Openshot. You can install it right from terminal:

```
sudo apt install openshot
```

While Openshot can do some more advanced things, you can also import audio add a video track and export your video. For more information regarding how to use openshot, see [this guide](https://www.openshot.org/user-guide/).

Comment: Thanks..... I'll give that a whirl this evening.
P.

Comment: I need to do some learning for this. It has worked, thanks, But the file size is a factor of ten larger than the ones done on the Windows Machine. I need to work it out, but it has worked. Thanks.
P.

Comment: @Piloti I'm glad to help! Please mark this answer as correct.